# How to correctly install TFServing via docker container

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I have tried to install TFServing in docker container several times.
However I still can't build it without any error.
I follow the [installation steps](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker) on the official site. But I still meet compile error during building.
I doubt that if there is some flaw in [dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel) which I built.
[I attach the screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti6VE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a dockerfile on the net which meet my demand.
https://github.com/posutsai/DeepLearning_Docker/blob/master/Tensorflow-serving/Dockerfile-Tensorflow-serving-gpu

Answer (score 0):

As of now (Oct 2019), official docker image of TFServing for both CPU & GPU is available at https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/serving.

To set up your tfserving image on docker, just pull the image & start the container.

**Pull the official image**

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving:latest
```

**Start the container**

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/model/dir,target=/models/inception --name tfserve -e MODEL_NAME=inception -t tensorflow/serving:latest
```

**For using GPU, pull GPU specific image and pass the appropriate parameters in docker command**

```
docker pull tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu

docker run -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/path/to/model/dir,target=/models/inception --name tfserve_gpu -e MODEL_NAME=inception --gpus all -t tensorflow/serving:latest-gpu --per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.001
```

**Please note,**

`gpus all` flag is used to allocate all available GPUs (*in case you have multiple in your machine*) to the docker container.

User `gpus device=1` to select first GPU device, if you need to restrict usage to a particular device.

`per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` flag is used to restrict GPU memory usage by the tfserving docker image. Pass its value according to your program need.